# Truth or dare program in java

Tags: java, beginner, random

I wrote this code in Java as a "Truth or Dare" game where if you type "truth" or "dare", it will pick a random number from the switch and then output the truth question or dare. The code works great but what I am looking for is critique.

I'm self taught and pretty new at coding so do you have any suggestions on cleaning up the code or how to layout the structure of the code?

Was there anything that I did that could have been done in a much simpler way?

And overall, how does it look for a newbie?

Anything helps and will be much appreciated! Thank you!

Hopefully I put the code below correctly.

````
    import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.println("TRUTH OR DARE?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Type type truth or dare!");
        System.out.println();
        
        int truth = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((18 - 1) + 1));   // Random number from 1-18
        int dare = 18 + (int)(Math.random() * ((36 - 18) + 1));  // Random number from 19-36
            
        String truthOrDare = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        
        if (truthOrDare.equals("truth") || truthOrDare.equals("Truth") || truthOrDare.equals("T") || truthOrDare.equals("true") || truthOrDare.equals("t")) {
            System.out.println(truth);
        } else {
            System.out.println(dare);
        }
    
        System.out.println();
    
    // TRUTH Cases ******************************************************************
        
        switch (truth) {
  case 1:
    System.out.println("When was the last time that you lied?");
    break;
  case 2:
    System.out.println("Have you ever pooped yourself?");
    break;
  case 3:
    System.out.println("What's your biggest fantasy?");
    break;
  case 4:
    System.out.println("What is a secret your parents don't know?");
    break;
  case 5:
    System.out.println("Who is your celebrity crush?");
    break;
  case 6:
    System.out.println("What is the most trouble you have been in?");
    break;
  case 7:
    System.out.println("Do you have a hidden talent?");
    break;
  case 8:
    System.out.println("What is the last lie that you told?");
    break;
  case 9:
    System.out.println("What was your most physically painful experience?");
    break;
  case 10:
    System.out.println("If you met a genie, what would your three wishes be?");
    break;
  case 11:
    System.out.println("Who was your worst kiss ever?");
    break;
  case 12:
    System.out.println("Who are you most jealous of?");
    break;
  case 13:
    System.out.println("Boxers or Briefs?");
    break;
  case 14:
    System.out.println("How do you really feel about the Twilight Saga?");
    break;  
  case 15:
    System.out.println("Have you ever peed in a pool?");
    break;
  case 16:
    System.out.println("If you were guaranteed to never get caught, who would you murder?");
    break;  
  case 17:
    System.out.println("Who is your hallpass?");
    break;
  case 18:
    System.out.println("Who would you hate to see naked?");
    break;  
        
    
    // DARE Cases ********************************************************************
    
  case 19:
    System.out.println("Show the most embarrassing photo on your phone!");
    break;
  case 20:
    System.out.println("Eat a raw piece of garlic!");
    break;
  case 21:
    System.out.println("Put 10 different available liquids into a cup and drink it!");
    break;
  case 22:
    System.out.println("Eat a Spoonful of mustard!");
    break;
  case 23:
    System.out.println("Show off your orgasm face!");
    break;
  case 24:
    System.out.println("Do your best sexy crawl!");
    break;
  case 25:
    System.out.println("Pole dance on an imaginary or real pole (if present)!");
    break;
  case 26:
    System.out.println("Drink Lemon juice!");
    break;  
  case 27:
    System.out.println("Eat a packet of hot sauce or ketchup!");
    break;
  case 28:
    System.out.println("Lick a bar of soap!");
    break;  
  case 29:
    System.out.println("Crack an egg on your head!");
    break; 
  case 30:
    System.out.println("Poor ice down your pants!");
    break;  
  case 31:
    System.out.println("Spin around 12 times and try to walk straight!");
    break;
  case 32:
    System.out.println("Eat a raw egg!");
    break;
  case 33:
    System.out.println("Put a clamp on your nipples!");
    break;
  case 34:
    System.out.println("Let everyone watch you whip and nay nay!");
    break;
  case 35:
    System.out.println("Say something dirty to the person to your left!");
    break;
  case 36:
    System.out.println("Do 100 squats!");
    break;
    
        }
        
        // Restart **********************************************************
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (type y/n and hit enter)");
        
        String y = myObj.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println();
        
        if (y.equals("y")) {
            Main.main(args);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ok, Bye!");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Do you care that you could get the same question multiple times in a row? Or do you want the set of questions to be exhausted first??

Comment: I havent really thought about that yet.  i was just going for random in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`myObj` is not a good name for your scanner.

You should not hard-code your random bounds, and you should replace your large `switch` with a random index into an array.

Don't recurse on `main()` after the player asks to play again - instead, just loop.

### Suggested

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;


public class Main {
    private static final String[] truths = {
        "What is your favourite thing?",
        "How are you doing?",
        "How fluffy are puppies?"
    };
    private static final String[] dares = {
        "Do something nice",
        "Be nice",
        "Take care of yourself"
    };

    private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        do {
            round();
        } while (playAgain());
        out.println("Ok, bye!");
    }

    public void round() {
        out.println("TRUTH OR DARE?");
        out.print("Type truth or dare: ");

        String truthOrDare = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        String[] source;
        if (truthOrDare.startsWith("t"))
            source = truths;
        else source = dares;

        int index = rand.nextInt(source.length);
        out.println(source[index]);
    }

    public boolean playAgain() {
        out.print("Would you like to play again [y|n]? ");

        String choice = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        out.println();
        return choice.startsWith("y");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, im such a noob! haha   I thought it looked decent but dang i was waaaayy off! I appreciate the great feedback!! thats the exact kinda thing i needed!   There is a lot i still havent learned so i think i just used what i did know for the moment.  

Thank you so much!!

Comment: ```String[] source= truthOrDare.startsWith("t") ? truths : dares;```
Use a more consistent style. If the "if" body is on a newline, the "else" body should also be on a newline.  Use of braces { } is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do. I put truths in a "Truth.txt" and dares in a "Dares.txt" file and a random line is generated from it.

````
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Truth_Dare {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("'TRUTH' OR 'DARE'?\n********************************");
        System.out.println("Type 't' or 'd'");
        char answer = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        switch (answer){
            case 't'-> System.out.println(Truth());
            case 'd'-> System.out.println(Dare());
        }
        System.out.println("\nType 'r' to run again 'q' to quit");
        char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        if (c == 'r'){main(null);}
    }

    static String Truth() throws IOException {
        final RandomAccessFile truth = new RandomAccessFile("Truths.txt", "r");
        final long randomLocation = (long) (Math.random() * truth.length());
        truth.seek(randomLocation);
        truth.readLine();
        String randomLine = truth.readLine();
        truth.close();
        return randomLine;
    }

    static String Dare() throws IOException {
        final RandomAccessFile truth = new RandomAccessFile("Dares.txt", "r");
        final long randomLocation = (long) (Math.random() * truth.length());
        truth.seek(randomLocation);
        truth.readLine();
        String randomLine = truth.readLine();
        truth.close();
        return randomLine;
    }

}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While this might be a good answer on stackoverflow, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The shorter the file, the likelier this is to fail. Hint: what happens when the file contains only one line?

Comment: @Reinderien i used file because there is a total of 30 questions, if there was only one question i wouldnt use files anyways. Why would there only be 1 line? and why would it fail?

Comment: If you randomly seek into the last line, only your first `readLine()` will work. The second will fail.

Comment: How can you use a random seek? It won't go the the beginning of a line.